# Bug report, Suse asks which component the package belongs. How can I tell?

Tags: opensuse, bugzilla

I have registered myself at [Suse's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.suse.com/) because I'd like to report a bug against a package, but when I open a new bug report I am asked the *component* against which I want to report a bug.

How do I query my system to know the *component* to which a package belongs?

Comment: Are you given any options? Do you have a "General" one? Is it free text? See point 3 in https://bugzilla.suse.com/docs/en/html/bugreports.html#fillingbugs

Comment: Just guess. They will still route the problem to the correct person regardless.

Comment: @Bib That's exactly what I've done.